# EMR/Spark slower with updated versions and better hardware

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

My team have created an updated EMR cluster to migrate all our pyspark data pipelines.

Versions update:

```
EMR: 5.29.0 -> 6.2.0
Spark: 2.4.4 -> 3.0.1
```

EMR Hardware update:

```
Master: 1 r4.xlarge -> 1 r6g.xlarge
Core:   2 m5.xlarge -> 1 r6g.xlarge
Task:   5 r5.xlarge -> 14 r6g.xlarge
```

We didn't change any code that wasn't been impacted by deprecated libraries.

Just as an example, to run the below code, the time we need went from 200s to 500s, but almost all of our codes are slower.

```
%pyspark
from datetime import date

df_lake = spark.read.format('csv').option("delimiter", "\t").load('s3a://sdite_bucket/data/raw/events_devices/')
df_lake.registerTempTable("snowplow")

maxrun = spark.sql("SELECT MAX(run) AS maxrun FROM snowplow").collect()[0]['maxrun']
```

I'm asking you help, because I have no idea where I should focus to solve this speed problem, do you suggest any of this topics?

- Hardware
- Deprecated Code
- Update libraries
- Spark config
- S3 connection

Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cloud-integration.html has a section on the best configurations for spark when reading/writing to object storage.

[image]

Comment: Hey, maksim, thanks for the answer. I tried all these configs but it didn't improve the speed. 
What I realized last week, is that tasks that loose performance are tasks that use spark.sql. I've checked the jobs in both clusters, and the one that performed better had 1 more spark task: ShuffledRowRDD. I think in some way spark is saving the data without sorting it, and it increases the speed significantly. I'm trying to enable that config or editing existing configs that may be impacting this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, I found this one https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-24-to-30. I think there were some changes to Spark SQL execution engine https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-3-0-0.html. It's possible to disable some of them and see if it improves the performance. Sorry, I don't have a definitive answer on why this is the case.

Comment: @lvgiac you were able to solve it? Because I was thinking of upgrading too, but now I'm scared of this problem.